# Passing a variable from a while loop to another class using org.json.simple json parser

Tags: java, json, parsing, while-loop

I am trying to get the variables TenderType, TenderAmount, and CrdName so I can send them to another class that will print them out. I do not think I can use getters and setters for this as I am declaring the variable inside the while loop for the org.json.simple parser to work. Still learning :/ Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Here is JSON:

{
    "Tender" : 
[
{
"TenderType" : "1",
"TenderAmount" : "21.00",
"CrdName" : "Visa"
}
]
}


//So for example the other class will be test() so

(FIRST CLASS)
 public class test{
  public String callvars(){
    JSONtoVar meh = new JSONtoVar(); 
   // ??? not sure the correct way to call any variable over???
   return "";
   }
  }

(SECOND CLASS)
//???Not sure what to do to return variables that are already declared inside of while Parser???
package json;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JSONtoVar {
  public int PARSEJson(){
    try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\interMind\\Desktop\\variables_json.txt"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray Tender = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Tender");

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Iterator z = Tender.iterator();
        while (z.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject innerObj = (JSONObject) z.next();

            //Trying to get these three strings Below   
            String TenderType = (String)innerObj.get("TenderType");         
            String TenderAmount = (String)innerObj.get("TenderAmount");
            String CrdName = (String)innerObj.get("CrdName");
            System.out.println("\nTender: \n" + TenderType + "\n" + TenderAmount + "\n" + CrdName);
            } 
          }
           catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();           
         }
   return 1;
  }
} //ends class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the method parseJson in class JSONtoVar, do following

   a.  Change return type of parseJson to Map

   ```
    public Map<String,String> parseJson(){.....  }
   ```

   b. Create a Hashmap

   ```
    HashMap<String, String> tender= new HashMap<String, String>();
   ```

   c. Add TenderType, TenderAmount and CrdNo in the HashMap.

   ```
     tender.put("TenderType",TenderType);
     tender.put("TenderAmount",TenderAmount);
     tender.put("CrdName",CrdName);
   ```

   d. Return HashMap to caller, return tender
2. In the calling method (test.callvars )create an instance of caller class and retrieve value from hashmap

   ```
   JSONtoVar jsonToVar=new JSONtoVar();
   HashMap<String, String> mapJson=(HashMap<String, String>)jsonToVar.parseJson();

   System.out.println("mapJson TenderType "+mapJson.get("TenderType"));
   System.out.println("mapJson TenderAmount "+mapJson.get("TenderAmount"));
   System.out.println("mapJson CrdName "+mapJson.get("CrdName"));
   ```

   Sample code

   ```
       public class myMain {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       JSONtoVar jsonToVar=new JSONtoVar();
       HashMap<String, String> mapJson=(HashMap<String, String>) jsonToVar.parseJson();

       System.out.println("mapJson TenderType "+mapJson.get("TenderType"));
       System.out.println("mapJson TenderAmount "+mapJson.get("TenderAmount"));
       System.out.println("mapJson CrdName "+mapJson.get("CrdName"));

      }

    }

    class JSONtoVar {

       public Map<String,String> parseJson(){

       HashMap<String, String> tender= new HashMap<String, String>();

       /*
           Get the value from JSON and set value.This has already be done          by you

       */

        tender.put("TenderType",TenderType)    ;
        tender.put("TenderAmount",TenderAmount);
        tender.put("CrdName",CrdName);


       return tender;



     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Exactly what I needed